# GWT- How to call an INSTANCE Java Method from Handwritten JavaScript?

Tags: gwt

I need to call an instance Java method from handwritten Javascript.  In the GWT docs it is explained how to do this with static methods and classes and it works fine:

http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit-doc-1-6/wiki/DevGuideJavaFromJavaScript  (Calling a Java Method from Handwritten JavaScript)

```
public MyUtilityClass
{
    public static int computeLoanInterest(int amt, float interestRate, 
                                          int term) { ... }
    public static native void exportStaticMethod() /*-{
       $wnd.computeLoanInterest =
          @mypackage.MyUtilityClass::computeLoanInterest(IFI);
    }-*/;
}
```

Is it possible to do this?  I tried several different combinations, declaring the native methods and using this.@ and instance.@ with no success.

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sure it is possible to do this but you syntax is wrong. I'm typing this without compiling, so I might have some typo's. But this is how I do it. The reason why your approach does not work is that the this variable is not what you would expect.

```
public MyUtilityClass{    
  public static int computeLoanInterest(int amt, float interestRate, int term)  { ... }    

  public static native void exportStaticMethod() /*-{       
      var _this = this;
      $wnd.computeLoanInterest = function(amt,interestRate,term) {
          _this.@mypackage.MyUtilityClass::computeLoanInterest(IFI)(amt,interestRate,term);    
      };
  }-*/;
}
```

Comment: Note that there is also a project called GwtExporter that can remove the needed for handwriting the JSNI calls. I haven't used it yet but the idea is very interesting.

Comment: How to pass this ---> (Context context, Element parent, String value,
      NativeEvent event, ValueUpdater<String> valueUpdater) from javascript to gwt-java code

Comment: those methods shouldnt be static

Comment: Is this really the answer?? Its weird because, I see the methods are still static. How did this solve your problem @Chinesco?

Answer (score 5):

I realise that this is old but I struggled to get this to work as David Nouls' answer wasn't complete for me. I had to tweak it like so to get initComplete() to call my instance method initComplete()

```
public static native void exportInitCallback(MyComponent thiz) /*-{
    $wnd.initComplete = function (){
        thiz.@my.package.client.MyComponent::initComplete()();
    }

}-*/;
```

On construction of MyComponent I passed *this* to my static method. The global initComplete method then correctly called the instance method.

I hope this helps some other GWT novice.

Answer (score 1):

David Nouls' answer works, with one correction:
remove the static keyword from the method declarations.

Answer (score 0):

Could you post the the code that is *not* working? :)

But the way I see it, `this.@` will not work, because you don't have an object of that class (in the handwritten JS, that is) and it would be the same as if you called an instance method of a class without creating an object of that class first.

`instance.@` should work, but you have to make sure that the `instance` points to a valid instance of the class at the time of the function call from the handwritten JS.